# How to display user's avatar on their profile page?

Tags: user-meta, profiles, avatar

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to display the user's avatar on their profile page. It seems like it would be a very simple thing to do, but I can't figure it out. Is get_avatar(); not the right way to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add any code *(make sure you add your own code next time because nobody bothers to help you if we have to guess the problem)* but Im pretty sure I know what's wrong.

Straight out of the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar):

```
echo get_avatar( $user_id_or_email, $avatar_size, $default_avatar, $alt_text, $args );
```

---

You **have to** `echo` it because `get_avatar()` doesn't output it by default.

Also make sure that *"Show Avatars"* is checked in *Settings* because it will not return avatar otherwise.